# label certain points with textxy()

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a volcano plot in R using the `plot` function and `calibrate` package in R and am trying to use the `textxy` function to plot only certain points.

Here is some data:

```
Metabolites <- data.frame(Metabolite = c("Glucose", "Galactose", "Creatine", "Lactose", "N-Acetylputrescine", "Tyramine", "Adenine", "Glycine", "Erythritol", "Choline"), Neg_pvalue = c(10, 8, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.7, 5, 3, 5.8, 4), LogFC = c(4, -3, 2, -1, 0.5, 0.7, 1, -2, -4, -1), padjust = c(1.453557e-19, 5.312771e-08, 4.983176e-02, 9.585447e-01, 2.449707e-01, 3.058580e-01, 4.223173e-02, 1.002379e-03, 4.466316e-27, 1.003879e-01))
```

Here is my code:

```
with(Metabolites, plot(LogFC, Neg_pvalue, pch=20, main="CNL", xlim=c(-5,6)))
with(subset(Metabolites, padjust <.05 ), points(LogFC, Neg_pvalue, pch=20, col="blue"))`
with(subset(Metabolites, padjust <.05 & abs(LogFC) > 2), points(LogFC, Neg_pvalue, ph=20, col="red"))
```

Now here is the issue:

```
with(subset(Metabolites, padjust <.05 & abs(LogFC) > 2), textxy(LogFC, Neg_pvalue, labs=Metabolite[1:3], cex=.5, offset = 0.2))`
```

If I plot this code, I get only the top 3 data points, as is indicated with the `labs=Metabolite[1:3]` part of the code. Alternatively, if I plot `labs=Metabolite`, then I get all labels.

If I wanted to plot the labels of only: Glycine, Lactose, and Erythritol as given in the Metabolites$Metabolite, am I able to do this?

Also, say I wanted to keep my top 3 data points labeled (`labs=Metabolite[1:3]`), but also want to label other metabolites of interest, say Tyramine and N-Acetylputrescine too; how can I do this?

Comment: Do NOT use backticks for code blocks. Use the [edit] braces. After fixing those errors, I get a warning that `ph` is not a graphical parameter and an error from not finding a function named textxy. You _should_ be using `library` calls for functions that are not in base packages.

Comment: (Also: salutations and postscipted thanks are discouraged.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work by slecting items that are in that set and using those character values as lables:

```
library(calibrate)
with(subset(Metabolites, Metabolite %in% c( 'Glycine', 'Lactose', 'Erythritol' )), 
    textxy(LogFC, Neg_pvalue, labs=c( 'Glycine', 'Lactose', 'Erythritol' ), cex=.5, offset = 0.2))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so very much. I tried to up-vote but unfortunately I cannot. Also, thank you for the 'edit' suggestion, above.